# How to use a object JSON from jade to local javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I try to use a JSON object (all the object not just a piece) from Node through Jade inside my local `myScript.js` script.

And my Jade file:

```
span(class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" onclick="confirm(\"#{myJSON.taskid}\", \"update\", !{myJSON})")
```

But I have this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myJSON is not defined.

Then I quit `!{myJSON}` as parameter in the call of function `confirm()` in `onclick()`, and I try with a script block:

```
script(type= "text/javascript" src="myScript.js").
    var local_json =!{JSON.stringify(myJSON)};
```

In `myScript.js` I issued `console.log(local_json)`, but I end up with the following error in the console:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: local_json is not defined`.

How I can do it?

Comment: You have to first create variable , then import your script file. so basicaly
<script> var local_json = !{JSON.stringify(myJSON)}</script>
then script ( type = "text/javascript" src="myScript.js")

Comment: I have answered question bellow so you can mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first create variable , then import your script file. so basically  var local_json = !{JSON.stringify(myJSON)} 
then import other script -  script ( type = "text/javascript" src="myScript.js")